# To make a noun to describe everything that is known well, would it be 'the well-known'?

Tags: nouns, hyphenation

For example, would there be a hyphen in the following sentence: "What exasperated him most was the well-known"? Or would it be: "What exasperated him most was the well known"? I know there may better/different ways to express the same sentiment ... But I'm interested in this particular usage. Does the hyphen belong there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you hyphenate combinations such as well known when they immediately precede a noun that they are modifying.

She is a well-known criminal.

Her criminal prowess is well known.

The difference in those two sentence is what *well* is modifying. If it's modifying a noun, then you can hyphenate them to indicate that those two words are functioning similarly to an adjective and are to be taken as a whole. On the other hand, if *well* is modifying the verb *known,* then it should be two separate words.

Comment: I understand how it works in those examples, but what about:

"What exasperated him most was the well-known." I know there may better/different ways to express the same sentiment... But I'm interested in this particular usage.

Or would it be: "What exasperated him most was the well known."

Comment: @jonathan If I were writing that sentence, I'd probably re-word it. It's *slighty* awkword. But if you keep it as is, I'd probably hyphenate it. You're using well-known as a noun, so you want it taken as a whole. A general rule of thumb would be that they are separate words when *known* is used as a verb. To be honest, it's more of a sin to hyphenate it when it shouldn't be hyphenated then it is the other way around. So when in doubt, either hyphenate it or rephrase it.